# GridView JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

How to check whether an ASP.NET GridView has atleast one row, using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView is rendered as an Html table so you just access it in javascript like

```
var grid = document.getElementById('<%=GridViewId.ClientID %>');
var totalrowcount = grid.rows.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

just wondering why count the Dom element

```
var _count = '<%=GridView1.Rows.Count %>';
var rowcount = (_count)?_count:0;
```

Answer (score 1):

using Jquery find the ID of your gridview

```
 var rowCount = $('#<%=gridview.ClientID%> tr').length;
```

rowCount will get the value of the total rows.If it is 1 then it contains only only headers.